# Get validator constraints of an entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I managed to inject the validator service into mine.

Now I can't figure out how to get the different constraints from an entity metadata .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// In your controller, get the validator:
$validator = $this->get('validator');

// Get Metadata for Class. You can use 'App\Bundle\Entity\YourEntity' as well
$meta = $validator->getMetadataFor(YourEntity::class);

// Used 'Default' as default Validation Group.
$constraints = $meta->findConstraints('Default');
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Tested on Symfony 2.8. For other versions you might need a slightly different approach. If this is not working for you, please update your question with the Symfony version you are using.