# Symfony 4 Getting Constraints Of an Entity returns empty array

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

I'm currently working on performing some custom validation to an entity using constraints (also custom ones) and the validator component. I want to get the specified constraints to an Entity by group to apply the correct constraints group.

I saw [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025778/get-validator-constraints-of-an-entity) for Symfony 2 and seems it doesn't work in Symfony 4.

The entity `User.php`:

```php
class User
{
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $origin;

   ...
}
```

The configured constraints in a `validation.yaml` file:

```
App\Domain\User:
  properties:
    origin:
      - NotBlank: { groups: [user_create] }
      - NotNull: { groups: [user_update] }
```

The validation process:

```php
// Get the component by injection and gets valid metadata
// Also gets the validation groups user_* for origin field
$metadata = $this->validator->getMetadataFor(User::class);

// This returns an empty array
$constraints = $metadata->findConstraints('user_create');

// This also returns an empty array
$constraints = $metadata->findConstraints('Default');

// Empty violations because constraints are empty
$violations = $this->validator->validate($leadRequest, $constraints, 'user_create');
```

Dump of `$metadata`:

```
ClassMetadata^ {#1551
  +name: "App\Domain\User"
  +defaultGroup: "User"
  +members: array:11 [
    "origin" => array:1 [
      0 => PropertyMetadata^ {#2472
        +class: "App\Domain\User"
        +name: "origin"
        +property: "origin"
        -reflMember: array:1 [
          "App\Domain\User" => ReflectionProperty {#2223
            +name: "origin"
            +class: "App\Domain\User"
            modifiers: "private"
          }
        ]
        +constraints: array:4 [
          0 => NotBlank^ {#5590
            +message: "This value should not be blank."
            +allowNull: false
            +normalizer: null
            +payload: null
            +"groups": array:1 [
              0 => "user_create"
            ]
          }
          1 => NotNull^ {#5567
            +message: "This value should not be null."
            +payload: null
            +"groups": array:1 [
              0 => "user_update"
            ]
          }

...
```

There is not any documentation about this feature so maybe this method is no longer valid or I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe cache clear ? where is your validation.yaml file ?

Comment: Why don't you simply call `$this->validator->validate($leadRequest, null, 'user_create');`?
I mean, if you need to perform a validation against a particular "group", just use it.
The `$constraints` field could be useful only if you need a "sub-set" of constraint under the same "group"

Comment: @VincentDecaux The cache clear trick doesn't make any changes and the validation file is in `config/validator/validation.yaml` as said in the validator docs.

Comment: Is your `User.php` in the right namespace?

And did you enable the validation as shown in https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#configuration

Comment: @DonCallisto That method works correctly but I need to perform some operations with the same constraints, that's why I need to get them.

Comment: @muffe Yes! `App\Domain`

Comment: My suspect is that the metadata are taken only from class. Take a look at [this](https://matthiasnoback.nl/2012/03/symfony2-writing-a-yaml-driver-for-your-metadata-factory/)

Comment: @DonCallisto I added an example of a dump of my `$metadata`. The weird thing is that the constraints are mapped correctly as metadata but the `findConstraints` method seems to be failing or something else.

Comment: Umh. BTW I still can't understand what you're trying to do; as a matter of fact your code should have the same behavior of what I've written before in my first comment.

Comment: @DonCallisto I want to apply dynamically the same constraints other entities and perform some other operations with it. Maybe this behavior is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must define what property you want to get constraint for.

This code works :

```
dd($metadata->properties['origin']->getConstraints());
```

But :

```
dd($metadata->getConstraints());
```

will return an empty array as well.

You can build your own group array :

```
$groups = [];
foreach ($metadata->properties as $property) {
    $constraints = $property->getConstraints();

    foreach ($constraints as $constraint) {
        foreach ($constraint->groups as $group) {
            $groups[$group] []= $constraint;
        }
    }
}
dd($groups);
```

Comment: It works but then I should iterate over all properties and the main issue is not solved because I want to get the constraints by a specific group. Maybe I should create my own method but it seems to be already implemented in the `GenericMetadata` class. That's why it doesn't have much sense to me

Comment: You can build your own function so, iterating through all properties, then all constraints to find every constraint you want. See my update

Comment: Thank you. Definitively is working, it seems is a valid temporal solution. But it keeps bothering me that  the `findConstraints` method should work but it doesn't. One issue of this solution is that in some custom constraints the `$this->context->getObject()` method returns null but I think is valid since the the constraints are manually built, using `$this->context->getRoot()` gives me the User object.